# Extract specific value from string

Tags: string, kotlin

I have a record of the type string. I want to grab the choice_value and make sure it's "OUT"

```
val failedRecord: myRecord <String>

myRecord(
meta=Meta(recordId=123, source=web, timestamp=2020-12-31T18:00:00Z, filename=null), 
record={"email":"test@gmail.com","source":"web","sub_source":"google","choice_value":"OUT","create_date":"2022-09-29T03:42:09.976-05:00","is_undeliverable":false}
)



if( failedRecord.record.(stuck on what to do here 
    but i need the value stored in Choice_value).equals("OUT"){
        // more logic
}
```

Comment: you can use an object mapping framework like Jackson to deserialize the record into a Record-Object and then use the getter. If that is to complicated you can make use of String.contains or use regex.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a data class for Record and it's subclasses.

```
        @Serialized
        data class Record(
        @SerializedName
        ("meta") var meta : Meta? = null,
        @SerializedName
        ("record") var record: record? = null)
    
        @Serialized
        data class record(
        @SerializedName 
        ("email") var email : String? = null,
        @SerializedName
        ("source") var source : String? = null,
        @SerializedName
        ("sub_source") var sub_source : String? = null,
        @SerializedName
        ("choice_value") var choice_value : String? = null

// Add the rest of the values for the data class record as well create a data class Meta...
        )
```

Your new code should look something like this

```
    lateinit var failedRecord : String
    val myRecord = MyRecord<Record>()
    failedRecord = myRecord.record.choice_value.toString()
```

You could then create a `when` statement. Something like

```
    when(failedRecord){
         "OUT" ->{
          // When OUT do something
                }
         "IN" ->{
         // When IN do something
                }
     }
```